# Specifying multiple assumptions in the integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I have to calculate following integral

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d \omega}{(i \omega +(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{p}).(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{p}) ) (-i \omega + (\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{p}).(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{p}) )} $$

where $ \mathbf{k},\mathbf{p} $ are d-dimensional vectors. Therefore:

```
int = 1/((I o + (k - p).(k - p)) (-I o + (k + p).(k + p)))
Integrate[int, {\o, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]},Assumptions -> {p > 0,k> 0}]
```

but it gives me

```
ConditionalExpression[0,Re[(k + p).(k + p)] < 0 && Re[(k - p).(k - p)] > 0]
```

It seems that mathematica counts `(k+p).(k+p)` as some different structure which has to be specified separately. I can do it by implying assumptions as

```
Assumptions -> {(k+p).(k+p) > 0,(k-p).(k-p)> 0}
```

But this gets really annoying when I have several different vectors like `k,p,r,s` and so on and all possible combinations of them.

How should I make it simpler?

Comment: If you just want to get the result without the `ConditionalExpression`, then simply `Normal[int]`.

Comment: Those scalar products has to be positive.... and If I do that, mathematica will choose some conditions and I wont see them.

Comment: Mathematica has no idea that `k` and `p` are vectors, or what those dot products might be. I'd suggest recasting the expression using symbolic expressions for the dot products, maybe `kmp2` and `kpp2` (for "k - p squared" and "k plus p squared" respectively). Then put assumptions in that they are positive.

Comment: Yes, that would be a good solution for this problem. But this is just a part of the whole program that I have and these forms are the most effective ones for the rest of the program.
For example I can have sum of any (finite) numbers of vectors there and then I have to perform Taylor series in powers of those vectors. I know how to do that, I just don't know how to set these assumptions in the most effective way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we could auto generate a condition that any vector `Dot` with itself is positive:

```
int = 1/((I o + (k - p).(k - p)) (-I o + (k + p).(k + p)));
Integrate[int, {o, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> (# > 0 & /@ Cases[int, Dot[a_, a_], Infinity]) ]
```

> (2 Pi)/((k - p).(k - p) + (k + p).(k + p))

Implicitly this assumes k!=p.  You could use `>=0` then you get a conditional expression that basically asserts that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you define all vectors in the first line.

```
$Assumptions = p > 0 && k > 0;
```

This will make it easy to follow.

Comment: Nope. Mathematica still things that (k-p).(k-p) is something different and can consider that product to negative....

Comment: @Versor295 So, define them as they are so that Mathematica don't confuse or do unnecessary assumptions. For example,  `$Assumptions = p > 0 && k > 0&& p \in Reals;` and so on. Define all of the vectors in detail.

Comment: I did that, but I still have the same result... I basically have the same conditional expression

Comment: Note the assumption is nonsense to begin with. What does it mean for a vector to be greater than zero?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the Dot-Products to be greater 0:

```
    int = 1/((I o + (k - p).(k - p)) (-I o + (k + p).(k + p)));

    Integrate[int, {o, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
    Assumptions -> ((k - p).(k - p) > 0 && (k + p).(k + p) > 0)]

    (*  (2 \[Pi])/((k - p).(k - p) + (k + p).(k + p))         *)
```